# Visual Studios 2012 Debug MVC App Opens Chrome Browser in Random Window

Tags: google-chrome, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0

Basically when I right click project --> Debug --> Start New Instance in visual studio 2012 with chrome as the default browser, it seemingly picks a random window instance of chrome browser and opens a new tab there.

My desired behavior is that it would open a new chrome browser window and then mvc web preview.  Or if there has already been an MVC debug instance launched, then it will open a new tab in that window.  I have no idea how it would be able to do this writing an extension or something.  But this opening of tabs in random chrome windows drives me nuts.  Especially when combined with VirtualWin (so these new windows from another desktop workspace get pulled into the current workspace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is default Chrome behavior rather than something from Visual Studio. Chrome uses the last window you had active as the place to add the new tab. You can test this out by clicking on a link from email (and assuming Chrome is your default system browser) watching where the new tab opens up.

It might be possible to pass command line arguments to Chrome to specify to open in a new window  but you would likely need to write a VS extension to do that.

Check out [Default Browser Switcher](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb424812-f742-41ef-974a-cdac607df921/) for one idea.

Answer (score 0):

This was changed in Visual Studio 2017, where Chrome will open a new private window by default to run the app in.

It *is* possible to pass command line arguments to the browser, though:

1. Click the down arrow to the right of the launch button where you select the browser.
2. Click "Browse With..."
3. Look at the path for Google Chrome and copy it.
4. Add a new browser
5. Paste the path in the "Program" box, put the command line arguments in the "Arguments" box, and put "Google Chrome" or some other name for the "Friendly name" that will be displayed. Putting the same name as something already existing will make it "Google Chrome (2)". If necessary, you can remove the existing one and replace it with your modified one. To do so, you must first set something else as the default, since the default one cannot be removed.

Note, I confirmed these steps in 2015 and 2017, but I think 2012 works the same way.

Try `/new-window` as an argument.